# How to make a categorical barplot with time series in Bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'd like to make a categorical barplot with timeseries on the x-axis.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    VRI    TIME      QTY
0   308 00:00:00    613.0
1   308 00:15:00    581.0
...
92  309 00:00:00    299.0
93  309 00:15:00    300.5
...
188 310 00:00:00    166.0
189 310 00:15:00    125.0
...
284 328 00:00:00    133.5
285 328 00:15:00    85.5
```

The VRI needs to be the categorical variable, so I'd like to create 4 bargraphs next to each other.

On the X-axis I would like to have the TIME column, which consists of all the hours of a day per 15 minutes.

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(vri_data)

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', title='Total traffic intensity per VRI', plot_width=1000)
p.vbar(x='time',top='aantal', width=timedelta(minutes=10), source=source, hover_line_color="black")

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Traffic intensity'

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=
                  [
    ('Time', '@time'),
    ('Traffic Intensity', '@aantal'),
    ('VRI Number', '@vri')
])

p.add_tools(hover)



show(p)
```

It outputs this:
[image: bokehplot]

In this plot all the 4 graphs are placed on top of each other, making some invisible. Now what I would like is to have 4 bargraphs next to each other instead of on top of each other, one for every distinct VRI value.

I have tried to use:

```
p = figure(x_range = vri_data['vri'], ...
```

But this outputs `ValueError: Unrecognized range input:`

Does anyone know a fix in order to get the plot as I want it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Turn the X axis to a proper categorical one, making each of those 15 minutes intervals a separate categories. That would allow you to use nested categories as described [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories) in the Bokeh documentation.
2. Do it all manually. Either add a `color` column to the data source and use specify the corresponding `vbar` parameter or just create 4 vbars, 1 for each `VRI` value.